# Unable to find code folder in the vagrant home directory

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to setup vagrant on my windows OS. I have watched some tutorial about that. 
According to those tutorial, I should be able to map some folder from windows to the vagrant machine . I have configured homestead.yaml file with below info :

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- /Users/Fakhreddin/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: Users/Fakhreddin/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
- homestead

variables:
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local
```

But when i check my vagrant home directory, there is no folder with **code** name 
I have tried to create it manually, But it doesn't work.

What's wrong with it and how to solve?

Comment: It looks like your `map` path lacks a trying slash, what if you change it to `/Users/Fakhreddin/code`?

Comment: Thank for comment. I have checked your suggestion. But it doesn't work.
The main problem is missing code folder in the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "Users/Fakhreddin/code", "/home/vagrant/code"
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder name is Code, with uppercase, the Linux machine is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

check VagrantFile ，find this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "D:/Project", "/home/vagrant/Code"
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer solves a problem. What you expect OP to see, and what he should do to solve the problem?